# Mi body con linear-gradiant siempre se muestra en blanco

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Intento hacer un degradado pero al momento de visualizarlo siempre se muestra en blanco como si las propiedades que le agrego al css estuviesen mal escritas o nunca las tomara, si dejo una sola propiedad como background: green; esta propiedad si la toma pero al momento de añadir las demás propiedas del body ya no se muestra nada

```css
body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgb(117,168,68);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(159deg, rgba(117,168,68,1) 25%, rgba(52,107,45,1) 73%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(159deg, rgba(117,168,68,1) 25%, rgba(52,107,45,1) 73%);
    background: linear-gradient(159deg, rgba(117,168,68,1) 25%, rgba(52,107,45,1) 73%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#75a844",endColorstr="#346b2d",GradientType=1);
}

#Logo {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Cargando recursos...</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/8.0.1/normalize.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets\css\style_encuestas.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="Logo">
        
    </div>
</body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.3/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

¿Que puede estar afectando que se muestre siempre en blaco el degradado?

Comment: Estuve revisando tu codigo, y coseguí que añadiendo contenido a un div me mostraba el color de fondo

Answer (score 0):

Podrías aplicar un alto de 100vh al body para que se adapte al total del alto de la ventana.

100vh = 100% de la altura de la ventana

100% = 100% de la altura del elemento principal

Las etiquetas html y body no tienen un tamaño por defecto.

```css
body{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgb(117,168,68);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(159deg, rgba(117,168,68,1) 25%, rgba(52,107,45,1) 73%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(159deg, rgba(117,168,68,1) 25%, rgba(52,107,45,1) 73%);
    background: linear-gradient(159deg, rgba(117,168,68,1) 25%, rgba(52,107,45,1) 73%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#75a844",endColorstr="#346b2d",GradientType=1);
}

#Logo {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Cargando recursos...</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/8.0.1/normalize.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets\css\style_encuestas.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="Logo">
        
    </div>
</body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.3/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</html>
```